# How can I roll my own progress bar using node-formidable project?

Tags: node.js, xmlhttprequest

I am very new in node.js.

I am currently working on a file upload service. I used xhr polling in client side as below:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var onProgress = function(e) {
    console.log(e);
};
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file_name_input', file_name_input[0].files[0]);
xhr.addEventListener('progress', onProgress, false);
xhr.open('post', 'http://ServerAddress/upload', true);
xhr.send(formData);
```

On server I use [formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable) and the code like that:

```
var http = require('http'),
    formidable = require('formidable');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
   if (request.url == '/upload' && request.method.toLowerCase() == 'post') {
       var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
       form.addListener('progress', function(bytesReceived, bytesExpected){
           response.write(bytesReceived);
       });
   }
});
```

My problem is this code did not roll my own Progress bar. How can I roll my own progress bar from client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start from looking at how existing library such as [jQuery File Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) implements progress bar. It uses [twitter's bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#progress) for rendering the progress bar